# How can check the distribution of a variable in python?

Tags: python, arrays, random, numpy, statistics

In a uni-testing I need to check the distribution of the values ​​of an array is uniform. For example:

in an array = `[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]`
there is a uniform distribution of values. Since there are four "1" and four "0"

For larger lengths of the array, the distribution is more "uniform"

How do I prove that the array that is testing has a uniform distribution?

note: the array is created with `random.randint(min,max,len)`, from `numpy.random`

Comment: Is the problem that you don't know how to determine whether a set of values is uniformly distributed, or that you can't implement it in code?

Comment: Exactly, I don't know how to determine whether a set of values (from a variable or array) is uniformly distributed.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is better suited to http://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: for continuous distributions there is [Kolmogorov–Smirnov test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test); for discrete distributions there is a [Chi-square test](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda35f.htm)

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I don't agree. The question is about how to do it in `Python`. If the question shows up in stats.stackexchange.com, the most likely response is 'for python question, go ask it to the python people next door in statoverflow'. Beside, if you spend sometime in stats.stackexchange.com you will see that community is mathematical statistics oriented rather than application oriented.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use Kolmogorove-Smirnov Test for continues *and* discrete distributions. This function is provided with `scipy.stats.kstest` http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.kstest.html#scipy.stats.kstest.

```
In [12]:

import scipy.stats as ss
import numpy as np
In [14]:

A=np.random.randint(0,10,100)
In [16]:

ss.kstest(A, ss.randint.cdf, args=(0,10))
#args is a tuple containing the extra parameter required by ss.randint.cdf, in this case, lower bound and upper bound
Out[16]:
(0.12, 0.10331653831438881)
#This a tuple of two values; KS test statistic, either D, D+ or D-. and p-value
```

Here the resulting P value is 0.1033, we therefore conclude that the array `A` is not significantly different from a uniform distribution. The way to think about the P value is, it measures the probability of getting the test statistic as extreme as the one observed (here: the first number in the tuple) assuming the null hypothesis is true. In KS test, we actually has the null hypothesis that `A` is not different from a uniform distribution. A p value of 0.1033 is often not considered as extreme enough to reject the null hypothesis. Usually the P value has to be less than 0.05 or 0.01 in order to reject the null. If this p value in this example is less than 0.05, we will then say `A` is significantly different from a uniform distribution.

The alternative method of using `scipy.stats.chisquare()`:

```
In [17]:

import scipy.stats as ss
import numpy as np
In [18]:

A=np.random.randint(0, 10, 100)
In [19]:

FRQ=(A==np.arange(10)[...,np.newaxis]).sum(axis=1)*1./A.size #generate the expect frequecy table.
In [20]:

ss.chisquare(FRQ) #If not specified, the default expected frequency is uniform across categories.
Out[20]:
(0.084000000000000019, 0.99999998822800984)
```

The first value is chisquare and the second value is P value.

Comment: even on the scipy page that you have linked to it is written that: "The KS test is only valid for continuous distributions."

Comment: @benhzad.nouri, if we were to dig this thing deeper, I think it is fair to say that if one apply KS test for discrete distributions, one can't estimate P as it is for continuous distribution (from the distribution of the D statistics). You can still do it, by simulation. See: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dgof/ (and actually has been proposed way back: http://oai.dtic.mil/oai/oai?verb=getRecord&metadataPrefix=html&identifier=ADA024845). I do have to check the source code of `scipy.stats.kstest` to see if `scipy` does the latter when the supplied `cdf` is a discrete one.

Comment: Hi @CTZhu, can you please explain what does this line mean ?

Comment: @CTZhu `FRQ=(A==np.arange(10)[...,np.newaxis]).sum(axis=1)` , you need the frequencies

Comment: Can I ask why ss.radint and not the uniform function?